# How to get user information in Azure function authenticated by Azure AD

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I have an angular App and an Azure Functions App. Both the apps are authenticated by Azure AD. While I am calling the function of Functions app after putting proper credentials, it is working fine. Angular app is appending the token with the call and it is used to authenticate the Azure function. 
However, in Azure function, based on user I need to put some logic, but not able to find how to get the information about the user who called the function. 
I tried ClaimsPrincipal to get the user information but it is not giving me information the user which I was expecting, rather it is returning Admin info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft Graph binding, specifically the [Auth token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph#auth-token) binding.

Just make sure you set the `identity` property's value to `userFromRequest` and then make a call to one of the [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) as shown in the doc.

For reference, here is the sample from the doc

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "token",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "graphToken",
      "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
      "identity": "userFromRequest"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**C# Script**

```
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Http; 
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging; 

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, string graphToken, ILogger log)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", graphToken);
    return await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");
}
```

**NodeJS / JavaScript**

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    let token = "Bearer " + context.bindings.graphToken;

    let options = {
        uri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': token
        }
    };

    rp(options)
        .then(function(profile) {
            context.res = {
                body: profile
            };
            context.done();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            context.res = {
                status: 500,
                body: err
            };
            context.done();
        });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not working getting below error while running Azure function with the mentioned code:

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the t
arget of an invocation. System.IO.FileSystem: Could not find a part of the path
'D:\home\data\byob_graphmap'.

Comment: Are you trying to run this locally? If so, you seem to be hitting an issue already reported [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension/issues/38). Also, do check out the [Local Development](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension#local-development) section of the readme.

Comment: I tried leveraging this approach, which works for 60 minutes then gives me the following error;

error invalid_grant error_description AADSTS500133: Assertion is not within its valid time range

Do we have to manage the token expiration manually? @PramodValavala-MSFT